# Sort array removing minimum number of elements

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

1. I have a large array, with thousands of records.
2. I want to get a sorted array in descending order. But I can't
   reorder elements. I can only remove elements, or fill elements with
   null.
3. The remaining elements (not removed) should form an array with
   descending order.
4. **Condition is that I have to remove minimum number of records and get maximum number of records in resultant array.**

Any idea about how to solve it? Maximum decreasing subsequence will not work, because I can remove elements from any place inside array. Not just two sides.

Comment: You need a search for "longest decreasing sequence".  Those algorithms will solve your problem; anything not in that sequence gets removed.

Comment: @Prune... Thanks a lot for your reply. But longest decreasing sequence can remove sequences which can be sorted by removing some intermediate values. In my case points can be removed from inside the sequence. Not just both sides.

Comment: Maximum decreasing sequence also includes removing internal elements.  You may be thinking of "slice", rather than "sequence".

Comment: The article in wikipedia is titled "Longest **increasing** subsequence", but you should be able to adapt it to "decreasing".

Comment: @Prune and user3386109 Thank you very much :).

Answer (score 0):

From comments of Prune and user3386109 and Prune I solved it in this way using PHP.

I took the algorithm from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence) using PHP, slightly modifying.

```php
function longest_decreasing_subsequence($x) {
  $p = array();
  $m = array();
  $p = array_pad($p, count($x), null);
  $m = array_pad($m, count($x) + 1, null);
  $l = 0;
  for ($i = 0; $i < count($p); $i++) {
    $lo = 1;
    $hi = $l;
    while($lo <= $hi) {
      $mid = ceil(($lo + $hi) / 2);
      if($x[$m[$mid]] > $x[$i]) {
        $lo = $mid + 1;
      }
      else {
        $hi = $mid - 1;
      }
    }
    $newL = $lo;
    $p[$i] = $m[$newL - 1];
    $m[$newL] = $i;

    if($newL > $l) {
      $l = $newL;
    }
  }

  $s = array();
  $s = array_pad($s, $l, null);
  $k = $m[$l];
  for($i = $l - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
    $s[$i] = $x[$k];
    $k = $p[$k];
  }
  return $s;
}
```